# jquery date picker not working with master page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, master-pages, jquery-ui-datepicker

jQuery `datepicker` not working with master page. `datepicker` not working while master page id added.

Please find the below code for more information.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
   <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" ref="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
   <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
   <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
   <script>
      $(function () {
         $("#datepicker").datepicker();
      });
   </script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
   <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: your code is fine. check jQuery and jQuery UI is loading properly.

Comment: its running without master page ., while adding master page its not responding

Comment: there is no body tag in your example. only title tag is there. jQuery also breaks if your html page have some problem.

Comment: i have to change date picker id . it changes after using master page. problem in id in javascript function

Comment: @kpsingh This is the `asp.net` syntax.

Comment: Thanks @mosh to letting me know

Comment: check if hasDatepicker class is added to your html in correct time or you have given it manually , usually people commit this mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an attribute [`ClientIDMode="Static`"](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2009/Nov/07/ClientIDMode-in-ASPNET-40) to save the `id` as is.

I recommend to use `class` instead but not overide the server generated ID.

Like:

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker" class="datepicker" />
```

Then:

```
$(function () {
   $(".datepicker").datepicker();
});
```

Comment: getting client side error- TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function

Comment: That's mean that you missing the `jquery-ui` reference. Please check that you've added the script and check if there are no errors in the `console` when the page load.

Comment: error - Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead.

Comment: And the `jquery-ui` reference? It's not make any sense because if you have the reference to `jquery-ui` you can use `.datepicker()` Do you have a public URL so I can see it?